# How to return the count of odd and even numbers in a list?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, literate-programming

Using a for loop in Python write code to iterate through every number in the list below to separate out even and odd numbers. Then return the number of odd and even numbers in the list.

my_numbers = [12, 21, 33, 14, 57, 6, 17, 10, 11, 28, 3, 32, 2, 4]

This is what I have so far:

```
my_numbers = [12, 21, 33, 14, 57, 6, 17, 10, 11, 28, 3, 32, 2, 4]
splitevenodd(A) 

def splitevenodd(A): 
   evenlist = [] 
   oddlist = [] 
   for i in my_numbers: 
      if (i % 2 == 0): 
         evenlist.append(i) 
      else: 
         oddlist.append(i) 
   print("Even list:", evenlist) 
   print("Odd list:", oddlist) 
    

my_evennumbers = ["Even list:"]
my_oddnumbers = ["Odd list:"]

print("The total count of numbers in my list is", len(my_numbers))

##counting the even numbers
#print("The count of even numbers in my list is", len(my_evennumbers))

##counting the odd numbers
#print("The count of odd numbers in my list is", len(my_oddnumbers))
```

I am not sure why this is not working. I am trying to get it to print how many numbers are in each, the even and the odd list. I think I am defining my_evennnumbers wrong but I am not sure how to define it in a way where it knows what I am asking it to count.

Comment: `my_evennumbers = ["Even list:"]` This creates a list containing one item, the exact string "Even list:".  Surely that isn't what you meant to do...

Comment: `sum(i % 2 for i in my_numbers)` gives the count of odd numbers. I leave the even numbers to you.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st execution point where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK.(Debugging fundamental.) PS There is no question in the body of this post. Please don't put something only in the title. (And per my last comment, bad code is not relevant to the title in the question.)

Answer (score 2):

I would use list comprehension for this one. This lets you assign the lists directly in a single line. Then you can just calculate the counts with only iterating over the list one.

```
my_numbers = [12, 21, 33, 14, 57, 6, 17, 10, 11, 28, 3, 32, 2, 4]

even_count = len([x for x in my_numbers if x%2==0])
odd_count = len(my_numbers) - even_count
```

Comment: Something to consider -- this forces you to iterate over the list twice! For very large data sets, this is certainly worse :)

Comment: Not anymore, it doesn't. If we're just looking for counts, we only need one list.

Comment: Assuming all numbers are integers.

Answer (score 2):

You could count the odds and then the evens are whatever is left over. A fast way is to use the `sum` function to add the first bit of each integer.

```
my_numbers = [12, 21, 33, 14, 57, 6, 17, 10, 11, 28, 3, 32, 2, 4]
odds = sum(number & 1 for number in my_numbers)
evens = len(my_numbers) - odds
print(odds, evens)
```

`sum` is implemented in C and will be a bit faster than modulos or conditionals written in python.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
def splitevenodd(A): 
   evenlist = [] 
   oddlist = [] 
   for i in my_numbers: 
      if (i % 2 == 0): 
         evenlist.append(i) 
      else: 
         oddlist.append(i) 
   print("Even list:", evenlist) 
   print("Odd list:", oddlist) 

my_numbers = [12, 21, 33, 14, 57, 6, 17, 10, 11, 28, 3, 32, 2, 4]

splitevenodd(my_numbers)
```

For it to work, I had to define the function first, then define the list, then pass the list to the function. The order of definition matters.

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers_even = [x for x in my_numbers if x % 2 == 0]

numbers_odd = list(set(my_numbers).difference(set(numbers_even)))

print(numbers_even)

print(numbers_odd)

[12, 14, 6, 10, 28, 32, 2, 4]
[33, 3, 11, 17, 21, 57]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because, while your function does separate out the evens and odds, it never *does* anything with those results. You could simply return the lists:

```py
def splitevenodd(my_numbers): 
    evenlist = [] 
    oddlist = [] 
    for i in my_numbers:
        if (i % 2 == 0):
            evenlist.append(i)
        else:
            oddlist.append(i)
    # let's omit the prints -- we don't care about seeing it on screen here
    # print("Even list:", evenlist) 
    # print("Odd list:", oddlist)

    return evenlist, oddlist

my_numbers = [12, 21, 33, 14, 57, 6, 17, 10, 11, 28, 3, 32, 2, 4]
evens, odds = splitevenodd(my_numbers)

print(f"""\
There are {len(evens)} even numbers: {evens}
There are {len(odds)} odd numbers: {odds}
Out of a total of {len(my_numbers)} numbers.""")
```

However, you might also want to consider different approaches. For instance, while it's not idiomatic in Python to approach the problem this way, what you are doing is called a "fold." Folds are implemented in Python using `functools.reduce`, which takes some an iterable, an initial value, and some function to apply. You could, for instance, implement `sum` by writing:

```py
def add(a, b):  # this is just operator.add
    return a+b

def sum(list_of_nums):
    """Folds using the add function"""
    return functools.reduce(add, list_of_nums, 0)

# if your list of numbers is...
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# then
result = sum(numbers)

# is going to start with 0+1=1 (the zero coming from the initial value)
# 1 + 2 = 3
# 3 + 3 = 6
# 6 + 4 = 10
```

You could use this to create your even and odd lists!

```py
def splitevenodd(my_numbers):
    # the function to fold with!
    def _inner(accumulator, next_):
        evens, odds = accumulator  # unpack the acc
        if next_ % 2 == 0:
            evens.append(next_)
        else:
            odds.append(next_)
        # return the next state of the accumulator
        return (evens, odds)

    initial = ([], [])  # (evens, odds)
    return functools.reduce(_inner, my_numbers, initial)
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"How to return the count of odd and even numbers in a list?*
>
> *Using a for loop in Python write code to iterate through every number in the list below to separate out even and odd numbers. Then return the number of odd and even numbers in the list. ..."*

Utilize a *"[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)"*.

Here is an example.

```py
a = [12, 21, 33, 14, 57, 6, 17, 10, 11, 28, 3, 32, 2, 4]
e = [x for x in a if x % 2 == 0]
o = [x for x in a if x % 2 != 0]
print(f'e, length= {len(e)}, {e}')
print(f'o, length= {len(o)}, {o}')
```

Output

```
e, length= 8, [12, 14, 6, 10, 28, 32, 2, 4]
o, length= 6, [21, 33, 57, 17, 11, 3]
```

> *"... I am not sure why this is not working. ..."*

I believe you may have added the incorrect code on the second line.
There is no *A*, and *splitevenodd* hasn't been defined yet.

```py
splitevenodd(A)
```

> *"... I am trying to get it to print how many numbers are in each, the even and the odd list. I think I am defining my_evennnumbers wrong but I am not sure how to define it in a way where it knows what I am asking it to count. ..."*

The *evenlist* and *oddlist* are part of the *splitevenodd* method scope, so you will not be able to access either from the enclosing scope.
Place these values outside and above the *splitevenodd* method.

```py
my_numbers = [12, 21, 33, 14, 57, 6, 17, 10, 11, 28, 3, 32, 2, 4]
evenlist = []
oddlist = []

def splitevenodd(A):
    for i in my_numbers:
        if (i % 2 == 0):
            evenlist.append(i)
        else:
            oddlist.append(i)
    print("Even list:", evenlist)
    print("Odd list:", oddlist)

splitevenodd(my_numbers)

print("The total count of numbers in my list is", len(my_numbers))

##counting the even numbers
print("The count of even numbers in my list is", len(evenlist))

##counting the odd numbers
print("The count of odd numbers in my list is", len(oddlist))
```

Output

```
Even list: [12, 14, 6, 10, 28, 32, 2, 4]
Odd list: [21, 33, 57, 17, 11, 3]
The total count of numbers in my list is 14
The count of even numbers in my list is 8
The count of odd numbers in my list is 6
```